# Prove that $AG \parallel BE$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> [image: width=]
> As shown in the picture, $E$ is a point outside the square $ABCD$
> Connect $BE,CE,DE$, point $F$ is on line $DE$
> Connect $AF$ to intersect line $DB$ at point $G$
> Suppose that $DE=DB, CE=CF, AG=EB$
> Prove that $AG \parallel BE$.

My thinking:
It seems very difficult and complicated to prove without any analytic method. But I believe there must be a proof through pure geometric methods.Unfortunately, I have no idea about how to use the giving conditions still.

P.S.
This question comes from [Zhihu](https://www.zhihu.com/question/49728302/answer/117661693) (there no one could solve it), and according to a comment, the original source is the junior high third grade research of the junior part of Nanjing Xuanwu Senior High School.

> The original Chinese version:
> [image]

Comment: Please share what you tried. Also: where did you find this problem?

Comment: Please give more information in the posted questoin on the level of the problem, year, book/contest/competition, author (if known), country region or even city, et caetera, this may be useful for later searches. Else, the present problem - as it stays - is not easy to search for, which key-words could be specific? (Square maybe only...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let us solve first **analytically**, then we see why there is no purely geometric argument for a **false** problem.

We may and do assume that the vertices of the square are
$$
A = (0, -1)\ ,\
B = (1, -1)\ ,\
C = (1, 0)\ ,\
D = (0, 0)\ .
$$
The point $E=(x,y)$ is constrained to be on the circle centered in $D(0,0)$ with radius $DB=\sqrt 2$, so
$$
x^2+y^2=2\ .
$$
The point $F$ is on the line $DE$, so it has the shape $(ax, ay)$ for some scalar $a$. The condition $CE=CF$ becomes:
$$
(1-x)^2+y^2 = (1-ax)^2+a^2y^2\ .
$$
The point $G$ is on $CB$, so it can be parametrized like $G=(g,-g)$.
The colinearity of $A,G,F$ becomes:
$$
0=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1\\
1 & g & -g\\
1 & ax & ay
\end{vmatrix}
\ .
$$
We have a final condition, $AG=EB$, which translates as
$$
g^2 + (1-g)^2 = (1-x)^2 + (1+y)^2\ .
$$
We obtain a system with four unknowns, and four equations.
There is one more hidden, tacit condition, namely $a\ne 1$.
So $(a-1)$ is invertible, we denote by $b$ the inverse:
$$
(a-1)b=1\ .
$$
Let us solve it the quick and dirty way, (the dirty part is determined by the problem itself, no alternatives to fit here in space,) am using [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) code:

```
R.<x,y,a,b,g> = PolynomialRing(AA)
eq1 = x^2 + y^2 - 2
eq2 = (1 - x)^2 + y^2 - (1 - a*x)^2 - a^2*y^2
eq3 = matrix(3, 3, [1, 0, -1, 1, g, -g, 1, a*x, a*y]).det()
eq4 = g^2 + (1 - g)^2 - (1 - x)^2 - (1 + y)^2
eq5 = b*(a-1) - 1 
J = R.ideal([eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5])

print('The real algebraic points in the variety defined by J are:\n')
for P in J.variety():
    AG_II_BE = bool(matrix([[P[g]    , -P[g] + 1], 
                            [P[x] - 1,  P[y] + 1]]).det() == 0)
    print(f'E = {(P[x], P[y])} with minimal polynomials:')
    print(f'{P[x].minpoly()} and\n{P[y].minpoly()}')
    print(f'Is AG || BE? {AG_II_BE}\n')
```

And we obtain:

```
The real algebraic points in the variety defined by J are:

E = (-0.3660254037844386?, 1.366025403784439?) with minimal polynomials:
x^2 - x - 1/2 and
x^2 - x - 1/2
Is AG || BE? True

E = (1.366025403784439?, -0.3660254037844386?) with minimal polynomials:
x^2 - x - 1/2 and
x^2 - x - 1/2
Is AG || BE? True

E = (0.5878272310746277?, 1.286257807131656?) with minimal polynomials:
x^8 - 5*x^7 + 21/2*x^6 - 9*x^5 - 9/4*x^4 + 10*x^3 - 51/8*x^2 + 11/8*x - 1/16 and
x^8 + 3*x^7 - 3/2*x^6 - 14*x^5 - 29/4*x^4 + 41/2*x^3 + 149/8*x^2 - 71/8*x - 193/16
Is AG || BE? False

E = (0.06116270957962576?, -1.412890343571248?) with minimal polynomials:
x^8 - 5*x^7 + 21/2*x^6 - 9*x^5 - 9/4*x^4 + 10*x^3 - 51/8*x^2 + 11/8*x - 1/16 and
x^8 + 3*x^7 - 3/2*x^6 - 14*x^5 - 29/4*x^4 + 41/2*x^3 + 149/8*x^2 - 71/8*x - 193/16
Is AG || BE? False

E = (0.3593190440690645?, 1.367804746507810?) with minimal polynomials:
x^8 - 5*x^7 + 21/2*x^6 - 9*x^5 - 9/4*x^4 + 10*x^3 - 51/8*x^2 + 11/8*x - 1/16 and
x^8 + 3*x^7 - 3/2*x^6 - 14*x^5 - 29/4*x^4 + 41/2*x^3 + 149/8*x^2 - 71/8*x - 193/16
Is AG || BE? False

E = (-0.9292974582794979?, 1.066023561669847?) with minimal polynomials:
x^8 - 5*x^7 + 21/2*x^6 - 9*x^5 - 9/4*x^4 + 10*x^3 - 51/8*x^2 + 11/8*x - 1/16 and
x^8 + 3*x^7 - 3/2*x^6 - 14*x^5 - 29/4*x^4 + 41/2*x^3 + 149/8*x^2 - 71/8*x - 193/16
Is AG || BE? False
```

---

In other words the claim is false. In best case, it is true with the probability $1/3$, and Schrödinger's cat had a better chance to survive then the author to dodge around this junior high school contest problem.

(There, where i am coming from, all contest get solutions to all the problems, the authors are named explicitly at least after the contest, and they have to provide a solution. Solutions of the participants are also made available, to show that the youth has under time pressure ingenious ideas.)

In order to still do something more geometrically, we will show it is true, when it it true, and make a picture showing it is false, when it is false. We are assuming that by "non-geometric means" (well, it is basicly algebraic geometry used above) the candidate points were isolated as above.
Below, $A,B,C,D$ are always drawn in a fixed coordinate system as mentioned above, so $D$ is placed in the origin, $\omega$ is the circle centered in $D$ with radius $DB$. In particular, any point $E\ne B$ on this circle is exterior to the square $ABCD$.

---

(1) The points
$$
\begin{aligned}
E_1
&=
\left(\ 
\frac 12(1-\sqrt 3)\ ,\
\frac 12(1+\sqrt 3)
\ \right)\ ,
\\
E_2 &=
\left(\ 
\frac 12(1+\sqrt 3)\ ,\
\frac 12(1-\sqrt 3)
\ \right)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We construct these points as follows.
Draw the parallel through $C$ to $DB$. It intersects $\omega$ in two points,
$E_1$, $E_2$, which sit in the plane as in the picture, $E_1$ in the second, $E_2$ in the fourth quadrant.

[image: math stackexchange 4445874 picture 01]

[image: math stackexchange 4445874 picture 02]

Let us obtain some more information about $E_2$. By definition $\widehat{DCE_2}=135^\circ$. In $\Delta DCE_2$ we know two sides, $DC=1$, $DE_2=DB=\sqrt 2$, so the third one denoted by $s=CE_2$ is obtained from
$$
-\frac {\sqrt 2}2=
\cos 135^\circ=
\frac{1^2+s^2-\sqrt 2^2}{2\cdot1\cdot s}\ .
$$
The positive solution of the obtained equation of second degree $s^2+s\sqrt 2-1=0$ is
$$
s=\frac 12(\sqrt 6-\sqrt 2)=\frac 1{\sqrt2}(\sqrt 3-1)\ .
$$
Then we compute in $\Delta CDE_2$ the angle in $E_2$,
$$
\cos \widehat{CE_2D}
=\frac{2+s^2-1}{2\sqrt 2 s}=\frac{2-s\sqrt 2}{2\sqrt 2 s}
=\frac{2-(\sqrt 3-1)}{2(\sqrt 3-1)}
=\frac{\sqrt 3}2
\ .
$$
So the angle in $E_2$ is $30^\circ$.
The angles in $\Delta CDE_2$ are thus $135^\circ$, $15^\circ$, $30^\circ$.
We find now the location of $E_2$ on the circle $\omega$, and the position of the points $F_2,G_2$ inside the square.

Let $C'$ be the reflection of $C$ w.r.t. the line $DF_2E_2$. So $CF_2C'E_2$ is a rhombus with angles of $60^\circ$ in $E_2,F_2$, so the triangles $\Delta CC'E_2$ and $\Delta CC'F_2$ are equilateral. Since $CF_2E_2$ isosceles, its angle $\hat F_2$ is the same as $\hat E_2$, $30^\circ$. This $\hat F_2$ is also exterior to $\Delta CDF_2$, so in this triangle $\hat C=\hat D=15^\circ$. So this latter triangle is isosceles.

Construct $\Gamma_2$ no so that $C'F_2D\Gamma_2$ is a rhombus. Here is a picture:

[image: math stackexchange 4445874 picture 02]

Then the rays $DC$, $DF_2E_2$, $DC'$, $D\Gamma_2$ are building angles of $15^\circ$, so $\Gamma_2$ is on $DB$. Since $C'$ is on the angle bisector of $\widehat{E_2DB}$ we also have $C'E_2=C'B$. In the isosceles triangle $\Delta DBE_2$ the angles in $B$ and $E_2$ are $\frac 12(180^\circ-30^\circ)=75^\circ$ each. So the angles in $B$ and $E_2$ in $\Delta C'BE_2$ are $75^\circ-30^\circ=45^\circ$ each. So the third angle is $\hat C'=90^\circ$. We obtain $\widehat{CC'B}=60^\circ+90^\circ=150^\circ$.

So $\Delta CC'B$ has angles $15^\circ$, $15^\circ$, $150^\circ$, same as $\Delta DF_2C$. Each of them has the the bigger side as a side of the square, so the two triangles are equal, and thus they can be obtained from each other by a symmetry rotation of the square.

Since $C'$ is on the side bisector of $BC$ and/or $AD$, and since $\widehat{CDA}=60^\circ$, the triangle $\Delta C'DA$ is equilateral. By rotational symmetry, $\Delta F_2AB$ is also equilateral. The angles $\widehat{DF_2A}$ and $\widehat{DF_2\Gamma_2}$ turn out to be equal, so $A, \Gamma_2,F_2$ colinear. So $\Gamma_2=G_2$, and then $G_2A\|E_2B$, since both lines make an angle of $60^\circ$ with $AB$.

This shows that $E_2$ "works" in the condition of the problem in question.

---

(The above argument could have been simplified to a few lines, if the configuration of the equilateral triangle $\Delta F_2AB$ inside the square
$\square ABCD$ is known.)

---

The point $E_1$ then also "works" by a Galois conjugation argument in the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$, which moves $\sqrt 3$ to $-\sqrt3$, i.e. exchanges $E_1$ and $E_2$. Geometrically, here is the picture for this situation:

[image: math stackexchange 4445874 picture 02]

Proof is skipped.

But picture is given to strengthen the point of the view of the asked question. Yes, is there any geometric argument that covers both cases pictured above, where the geometric constellations happens to show $AG\|BE$?
This is a question to the author of this contest problem (and to those who inserted it also in the list - very probable without trying it any ten seconds).

---

---

Now let us illustrate in pictures some cases, where the claimed property is false.

[image: etc05]

[image: etc06]

[image: etc07]

[image: etc08]

The pictures were drawn using geogebra. The four $E$-points were declared with some numerical white noise, the results also get this white noise.

To have a proof for the existence of the one or the other point $E$, for instance $(-1.41289034357124\dots,  \ 0.0611627095796257\dots)$ one can proceed as above, let $E$ run on a small (or big) arc on the circle $\omega$, construct $F\in DE$ so that $\Delta CEF$ is isosceles, then construct $G$ as the intersection $G=AF\cap DB$, then consider the expression
$$
AG-BE
$$
as a function of $E$. It changes sign near the solutions, so a continuity argument is  needed, which is not available for the level the problem was proposed for. All in all, this is a bad problem for a contest, beyond the fact that it is false, this may happen, there is no way to save the day and have at the given level a chance to find out under time pressure that it is false, and possibly have arguments for this.

Comment: It's worth noting that only one of the six possible configurations has $G$ *between* $B$ and $D$ (and $F$ *between* $D$ and $E$), and this is one of the two cases where the parallelism property holds. If, as sometimes happens, the phrasing "on line [$PQ$]" is intended to mean "on *segment* [$PQ$]", then the question is actually valid. ... That said, it's not clear to me how one might structure an argument in which the other configurations are easily dismissed, especially in a time-(and technology-)constrained setting. So, even in "valid" form, the question may not be appropriate for a contest.

Answer (score -1):

From AG = BE (the given) and AG || BE (a result if true), we must have ABEG being a parallelogram.

This implies CDGE is also a parallelogram with CE || DG and $\angle DCE = 135^0$.

That further means E is not just **any** point outside the square ABCD.